# Stored procedure as Updatable Form Recordset

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

1. I'm trying to set up a form with a recordset based on a stored procedure on a MySQL server. It works like a charm when i use the command object and then `Set Me.Recordset = cmd.execute`, but i need to be able to update two fields (tinyint and varchar) bound to a checkbox and a textbox on my form. That, of course, doesn't work.
2. Seeing as that doesn't work by design, i tried to open the recordset with the .Open method and with the "CALL `procName` ('value1', 'value2');" syntax, and then create a new disconnected recordset, fill the schema from the .Open method and then, loop through the records and append to the new rs. Finally, set it up as the form's recordset like so:
3. ```
    Dim OriginalRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Field As ADODB.Field

    Set NewRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set OriginalRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    OriginalRecordset.Open "CALL `DosarClient_Functie` ('14575','2234');", SQL_ADE.Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText

    For Each Field In OriginalRecordset.Fields
      NewRecordset.Fields.Append Field.Name, Field.Type, Field.DefinedSize, adFldIsNullable Or adFldUpdatable
    Next Field

    NewRecordset.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    NewRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    NewRecordset.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    NewRecordset.Open

    OriginalRecordset.MoveFirst

    Do Until OriginalRecordset.EOF
       NewRecordset.AddNew
       For Each Field In OriginalRecordset.Fields
          If Not IsNull(Field.value) Then
              NewRecordset.Fields(Field.Name).value = Field.value
          Else
          End If
       Next Field

       NewRecordset.Update
       OriginalRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set Me.Recordset = NewRecordset
   ```
4. Extra: the NewRecordset variable is declared as private at form level. I also know is bad practice to call the procedure as i did, but i can think of no other way to accomplish this task.
5. Important: i can't and don't want to use a local table. that would be the easy way out, but it would also be inconsistent with the rest of the code.
   Thanks :)

The problem: if i proceed like i explained i get #Name error on the bound fields, or they are set to the recordset, i can change their value, but i don't see the initial value.